# Why can't I get name plus email format from database with PHPMailer

Tags: database, email, format, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email to a list of emails from a database using PHPMailer. There are two types of emails formats in the database. 1 is just the email address and 2 is name plus email address.

```
bsmith@somewhere.com vs Bob Smith <bsmith@somewhere.com>
```

The first one sends fine but the second one gives an error 
"Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

When I var_dump it I get "Bob Smith" but no email.

The relevant parts of the code are

```
$to = $row['email'];
$mail->AddAddress($to);
```

I know I can explode the email and get rid of the name but there should be a way that PHPMailer can handle it. It works fine using PHP mail().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These two formats are from RFC821 (SMTP) and RFC822 (MIME messages) respectively.

PHPMailer requires you to specify the name and address parts separately. Parsing email addresses is already horribly fraught, so it's more reliable to require the name and address separately, and is implemented like this:

```
$mail->addAddress('bsmith@somewhere.com', 'Bob Smith');
```

It works with `mail()` because mail does not send using SMTP, but only submits to a local sendmail, and doesn't usually need the address separately from the name.

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/146) to add parsing of RFC822 addresses to PHPMailer, but it's broken at the moment and the original author has not updated it - feel like fixing it? [This ticket](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/82) has some functions that may be of use here too.